# Wifi Drops Connections with WPA2-PSK

Tags: wifi, wpa, wpa2

I run a small computer lab made up of 10 computers of identical hardware and software (Dell Latitudes with Windows 7 x64 Enterprise) and I use a ZyWALL 2WG as a router/firewall.  Nine of the computers connect to the router over wifi using WPA2-PSK encryption while the last one is connected by ethernet cable.

I'm having a problem where any computer connected to the wi-fi occasionally drops off the network (it cannot be pinged and the client cannot ping the gateway).  It only happens on the wifi side and only when the encryption is WPA2-PSK or WPA-PSK.  I tried using another router with a different make and model and had no problems.  Thinking it could be a software error, I reset the router to factory defaults and installed the newest firmware (V4.04(AQI.8) | 04/09/2010), but still have the problem.  The  802.1X log gives the following error `User logout because of user disassociation.` with this note `WPA2-PSK:00242c582ece:logout` where 00242c582ece is the mac address of the device.

At this point I'm out of things to try and leads to follow.  It looks like [this](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-internet-wireless/f/3324/t/19276739.aspx) user had the same or similar problem, but none of those proposed solutions work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Wireless scanner, Inssider http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/
This will show you any interference on the channels and output power of the device.

Comment: That's a good idea, but inSSIDer didn't find anything.  Other wireless interference could be the issue, but I doubt it as I didn't have any problems with the other router and I don't have any problems when I turn off the wifi encryption.

Comment: InSSIDer will only show interference from other 802.11 networks. There is plenty of other noise like Bluetooth that cramps the 2.4Ghz band.